# AngularJS validation of HTML5 input date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have an AngularJS application, where I am using a HTML5 input type date control. I want to validate the control to restrict only to dates prior to today (including today).

I tried `max={{new Date()}}` value and tried to set, but does not seem to work.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to create simple dedicated validation directive that would properly add validation states to input and parent form:

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('main', function($scope) {
    $scope.startDate = new Date('2015-12-30');
})
.directive('minDate', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            
            var minDate = scope.$eval(attrs.minDate) || new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
            
            ngModelController.$validators.minDate = function(value) {
                return value >= minDate;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="main">
    
    <form name="testForm">
        <input type="date" name="date" ng-model="date" required min-date="startDate" />
    </form>
    
    <div ng-if="testForm.date.$error.minDate">Select date after {{ startDate | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy' }}.</div>
</div>
```

This directive would be also easily reusable. Say if you want to have today as minimal date the just use `min-date`

```
<input type="date" name="date" ng-model="date" min-date />
```

However, you can use arbitrary date that you can pass from controller:

```
<input type="date" name="date" ng-model="date" min-date="startDate" />
```

where in controller you could have

```
$scope.startDate = new Date('2015-12-30');
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox, which doesn't currently support type="date", will convert all the values to string. Since you (rightly) want date to be a real Date object and not a string, I think the best choice is to create another variable, for instance dateString, and then link the two variables:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="dateString" />
function MainCtrl($scope, dateFilter) {
    $scope.date = new Date();

    $scope.$watch('date', function (date)
    {
        $scope.dateString = dateFilter(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    });

    $scope.$watch('dateString', function (dateString)
    {
        $scope.date = new Date(dateString);
    });
}
```

See Fidler Demo Here:
[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/Vq65z/13/)
The actual structure is for demonstration purposes only. You'd be better off creating your own directive, especially in order to: